# TestCafe - Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Started to get `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` in random places using TestCafe.

I have a local node module that is a wrapper on `createTestCafe()` api. Module is called `testcafe-runner` and is installed like this `"testcafe-runner": "file:local_modules/testcafe-runner"`.

I started to get the error with the following exception:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at RequestPipelineContext.redirect (C:\MyTests\local_modules\testcafe-runner\node_modules\testcafe-hammerhead\lib\request-pipeline\context.js:278:9)
    at TestRun.handlePageError (C:\MyTests\local_modules\testcafe-runner\node_modules\testcafe\src\test-run\index.js:287:13)
    at SessionController.handlePageError (C:\MyTests\local_modules\testcafe-runner\node_modules\testcafe\src\test-run\session-controller.js:43:36)
    at error (C:\MyTests\local_modules\testcafe-runner\node_modules\testcafe-hammerhead\lib\request-pipeline\utils.js:81:48)
    at DestinationRequest.<anonymous> (C:\MyTests\local_modules\testcafe-runner\node_modules\testcafe-hammerhead\lib\request-pipeline\utils.js:62:9)
    at DestinationRequest.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at DestinationRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at DestinationRequest._onError (C:\MyTests\local_modules\testcafe-runner\node_modules\testcafe-hammerhead\lib\request-pipeline\destination-request\index.js:171:17)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\MyTests\local_modules\testcafe-runner\node_modules\testcafe-hammerhead\lib\request-pipeline\destination-request\index.js:93:40) {
  domainThrown: true
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 7
```

All test javascript files are located in C:\MyTests folder.

Version of testcafe 1.8.4 installed on both local_module and project

Comment: The information you provided is insufficient to determine the cause of the issue. Please share the module you mentioned and a sample test case that we can run on our side to diagnose this behavior. Or, better yet, submit a bug report at [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and fill-in all the information to reproduce the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes, I can imagine that it might be insuffucient. We have very complex test suites driven by json files and our system under test is on test env. with integration with telephony systems etc. so it would be impossible to run the test even if I provide the full source code. However problem is solved now by downgrading version of testcafe in all modules to explicit "1.8.1"  which comes with testcafe-hammerhead 16.0.2. I suspect, however I might be wrong, that the issue might have been introduced between 16.0.2 and 16.2.3 of testcafe-hammerhead.

Comment: I think that downgrading TestCafe is only a temporary solution. It's better to find the cause of the real issue. There were a lot of changes in `testcafe-hammerhead ` between versions `16.0.2` and `16.2.3`, so it's impossible to detect the problem without a project. We understand that it's very difficult to provide a full project integrated with other services, however, we would really appreciate it if you can extract the problematic part and share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the exact error.

```
testcafe - 1.8.4
OS - Mac Catalina
browser - chrome 81 
Node - 12.16.3
```

This is happening while clicking on a `logout` button.
There is 302 redirection happening and ultimately user is redirected back to login page.

The test cafe browser url is shown as at failure `http://localhost:1337/03WvIUCEQ/about:error`